# Why returns NULL after running select query the second time

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have select query that selects student scores and ranks them from the highest to the lowest, this mysql query works the first time, but when I run it the second time on phpmyadmin, it returns NULL where it is supposed to show the rank of the student, below is the mysql query;

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
     , student_name
     , avga 
  FROM `averaga` 
 WHERE class="Form 1A" 
 ORDER 
    BY avga DESC
```

here is a part snapshot of the results from query results
[image: part snapshot of the results from query results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable.  I usually do this in query itself:

```
SELECT (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank, student_name, avga
FROM `averaga` a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) params
WHERE class = 'Form 1A'
ORDER BY avga DESC;
```